# UI5 DataBinding Path issues

Tags: xml, sapui5

I have a `sap.m.SelectDialog` which looks like this:

[image: SelectDialog Multiple]

As you can see I have added a description "**Status: New**" to the list which can be achieved like this:

```
itemListTemplate: new sap.m.StandardListItem({
    title: "{SFC/#text}",
    description: "Status: " + "{STATUS_DESCRIPTION/#text}"
})
```

The data for the list comes from a XML-structure which looks like this:

[image: XML List]

The data binding happens here:

```
oSelectDialog.bindAggregation("items", {
    path: "/modelData/Rowsets/Rowset/Row",
    template: new sap.m.StandardListItem({
        title: "{SFC/#text}",
        description: "Status: " + "{STATUS_DESCRIPTION/#text}"
    })
});
```

**So far so good, everything is working fine :-)**

The problem occurs, when my XML-structure only has **1 row**

[image]

After binding the data to the table, the result looks like this:

[image]

What is wrong? :-) Any guess?

Comment: I would have expected the list to show empty items in both cases, because there is no *#text* node in the xml. the syntax should be `text()`.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the problem is with XML format: in the first case the path returns an array of Row which is then iterated on for the template, in the second case it returns a single Row and the iteration occurs on the members of this Row. I would Change the XML model to:

```
<Rows>
    <Row>
         <SFC>RW1</SFC>
    </Row>
    <Row>
         <SFC>RW2</SFC>
    </Row>
    ...
</Rows>
```

(same as your columns)